# Using plotly.express line chart, lines are connecting in weird order? How to fix?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly-express

[image]

Having a df of data, doing:

```
fig=px.line(df, x='date', y='px', color='description')
```

The following graph is rendered like the image attached. Is this an expected behavior? How do I make dots connect only in a time-ordered fashion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is observed in plotly plots.

The data is required to be `sorted` before the plotting.

Comment: @Stevie , did the above answer resolve your problem?

Comment: yes, sorting df before worked!